# How to share authentication between apps nodejs/react auth0 when separating parts of the app between admin/non-admin users

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, authorization, auth0

I am having a tremendously difficult time understanding how to separate a react app into login/admin/client and share the tokens from the login to client/admin after authentication with auth0

[this](https://github.com/daggala/secured-routes/blob/main/server.js) article explains how to use nodejs to serve up different parts of the app at a time, which is what I want for complete separation. There are so many SO threads about this but I can't seem to find anything anywhere about how to achieve this when integrated with auth0.

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34376954/splitting-react-app-to-2-independent-parts) is one saying to use code-splitting in webpack, but every tutorial for webpack/nextjs wateva just uses fake authentication.

My react app is separated into 3 SPAs: login, admin, non-admin.

So the flow should go:

| step # | client-side | nodejs server-side | auth0 token-serving |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | visit homepage -> | nodejs receives request for login SPA |  |
| 2. | client browser <- | nodejs sends back login SPA |  |
| 3. | client presses login button -> | nodejs receives request for authentication |  |
| 4. |  | nodejs sends request to auth0 for authentication -> | auth0 receives request for authentication |
| 5. |  | nodejs receives token <- | auth0 sends token |
| 6. | client receives admin/non SPA **WITH TOKEN** <- | nodejs sends admin/non SPA |  |
| 7. | client makes call to API -> | nodejs receives call from client and checks **VALID TOKEN** |  |

I am lost as how to authorize the admin/non-admin SPAs based on authentication having taken place in the login SPA! What am I missing here?! How does step #6 occur on the server-side?

Do I need to share tokens between the apps? How? Where does this happen? Do I need to use nodejs server-side authentication as detailed [here](https://auth0.com/blog/complete-guide-to-nodejs-express-user-authentication/) then render the token into the SPA before serving? Do I need to set cookies or something? Is the session cookie already set? How then does the auth0-react object in the admin/client SPA know? What is it that I'm missing here?

---

**EDIT:** I may have found a solution [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/server-side-rendering-your-react-app-in-three-simple-steps-7a82b95db82e/) with server-side rendering. It may be that I can either:

a) inject the desired app straight into the loginSPA via the App component and on client-side place a call to API with token instead of rendering a straight App component

e.g.
index.js:

```
<>
   {fetch(token)}
</>
```

b) simply render server-side and pass in the token via the initialState parameter.

e.g.
src/server.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from './redux/configureStore';
import App from './components/app';

module.exports = function render(initialState) {
  // Model the initial state  
  const store = configureStore(initialState);
  let content = renderToString(<Provider store={store} ><App /></Provider>);
  const preloadedState = store.getState();
  return {
    content,
    preloadedState
  };
};
```

However, I'm not sure if this will solve token refresh or logout/login redirect on token expiry. Will need to test and report back which may take some time as modern SSR and Redux are both new for me.

---